# Google play services after importing to AS from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I just imported a project from Eclipse to AS. In the project I'm using Google Maps, and in Eclipse I had these lines in the manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY">
```

Importing the project left these lines. Do I still need them in the manifest now when using Gradle or can I just add this line to gradle.build and thats it?

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Comment: You need the `classpath` line in the other Gradle file. You should also split the Google play services into those you actually need rather than compile all of them.  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split  and https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: What is the classpath line? Is that the one I posted in my question? And does it mean I can remove the meta-data lines from the manifest?

Comment: Oh I just see its in the link you gave me. Does the classpath line belong to the project gradle file or app gradle file?

Comment: You could answer yourself if you create a new google maps project on Android Studio and see the gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer- **you need both**!

Explanation (if you require it)

The Gradle lines basically tell Gradle to pull in the library called 'com.google.android.gms:play-services' and the version '9.4.0'. This is just a bunch of code you'll want to include in your project. (It's a lot of code, when your project looks bigger you'll want to split that out into just the components you use)

Meta data is used for different things than Gradle dependencies are- specifically in your case, you are using it here to:

- supply your google api key, and,
- supply your google play services version number

**NOTE: hide your API key!!!!** (just google "why should I hide my api key")

The version number is the version that your app expects to use, which you might specify if you are working on an older version, or for a workaround. Typically, these fields are just used to show maps.

The API key is used to access your Web Console app client for your app- i.e., the app on Google API Console that you linked to your Android Studio app. This is **not** something you want publically exposed on Stack Overflow.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Theres something wrong with what I'm doing.. The manifest file does not recognize the @integer/google_play_services_version and I've read that one I refer the play services to my project, the integer is supposed to be resolved automatically. What might be the problem with the way I added play services to my project?

Comment: That's something that comes up now and again. If cleaning (build/clean project) and building again doesn't fix it, then you might have a mismatched Play Services version, or something else out of date. Update your question with some code and a stacktrace and I should be able to help. You don't include the @integer/google_play_services_version in your project, it is added by the google library, so you can't really change it. You should be able to hardcode it but you don't want to do that

Comment: also check that you do actually need it, because I don't have it in the app I'm working on and it works fine with maps. However, you could still need it in your case, just ensure that you do if this is holding you back

Comment: It could be because of other issues I got.. mind taking a look at another question I posted and you might be able to solve both at once:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482184/packages-from-library-module-not-found-in-main-module

Comment: Your issue can be a number of things, so I would have to dig at it. If it builds and you have all these issues, my advice would be to remove all the Jars, comment out code whatever until you can build, then add them one-by-one clean/build after each and uncomment code, check it's going in. Make sure you are not building in release also, and it wouldn't hurt to check if the Jars are building and don't have any kind of obfuscation run on them when they are jar-ified (or your classes won't be there at runtime). That issue shouldn't really cause this one - try updating to google services 9.8.0.