# Packages from library module not found in main module

Tags: android, android-studio, module, android-library

I got a project which I imported from Eclipse to Android Studio. In Eclipse everything worked well.

It contains a main module (a project in Eclipse) which uses packages from a library module (library project in Eclipse). Since the migration did not went well, I have created a library module manually and just copied all the source code to the newly created module.

The problem is that the main module doesn't seem to find the packages from the library module and when I rebuild the project I get errors like "package bla bla does not exist".

Here is the main module gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pointer.mamagoose"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':linphoneclean')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile files('libs/firebase-client-android-2.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
}
```

linphoneclean is the library module.

The entire project's settings.gradle:

```
include ':linphoneclean'
include ':tigris'
```

This is the build.gradle of the library module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/linphone.jar')
    compile files('libs/firebase-client-android-2.5.0.jar')
}
```

The structure of the library module includes for example folder:
src/main/com/pointer/linphone    (and inside there are all the java files with a deceleration of `package com.pointer.linphone`, Yet I still get an error saying >"package com.pointer.linphone does not exist).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I see you didn't specify path to your module project for linphoneclean and tigris. As you can see from my answer where you asked to look to this question settings.gradle contains two things first "incluse..." second path to module. Example: 
include ':facebook'

project(':facebook').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../dependencies/FacebookSDK')

Comment: Have you ever managed to find the root cause? I'm having a similar problem :(.

Comment: Sorry to say but no.. In this case I had a small enough library so I just added it to the main project.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue. I had a working project which I opened after couple months in a new system with newer version of Android Studio. I've tried clean/rebuild, but nothing is working. To test this out, I create a brand new project. Create a Common library module (that has google guava dependency), included the Common module in the main App project. But the App project cannot see any guava package. This is crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fighting with the same issue for hours here is what worked for me.

I've created a fresh project with blank activity, added a library module with a dummy class, defined the dependency. Verified that it works by importing the dummy class in the app. Then I copied all my relevant code from the real project.

My thinking is that it was probably issue with IDE's iml files, since starting from scratch and copying stuff over worked.

Comment: I won't test it now after all this time passed since I asked the question, but since its only answer that seems logical, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

See properly source file contains both java folder and res folder,add java files in java packages and res in res folder.Add Activity name in Manifest file see here ,add necessary libraries files in Gradle file.Clean and rebuild the project in the Android studio.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: I might have missed something in your answer but of course my java files are in the src folder and resources in the res folder..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if the library's AndroidManifest has defined the package correctly, like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.pointer.linphone">
```